# generate xquery using given output

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to generate xquery using given output.
My XML is as follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <S_db>
    <student id="94811">
    <name>Rusty Nail</name>
    <quizzes>
        <quiz>16</quiz>
        <quiz>12</quiz>
    </quizzes>
    <projects>
        <project>44</project>
        <project>52</project>
    </projects>
    <exams>
        <exam>77</exam>
        <exam>68</exam>
        <exam>49</exam>
        </exams>
    </student>
    <student id="2562">
    <name>Guy Wire</name>
    <quizzes>
        <quiz>15</quiz>
        <quiz>23</quiz>
    </quizzes>
    <projects>
        <project>33</project>
        <project>47</project>
        </projects>
    <exams>
        <exam>78</exam>
        <exam>86</exam>
        <exam>88</exam>
    </exams>
    </student>
    <student id="137745">
    <name>Barb Wire</name>
    <quizzes>
        <quiz>20</quiz>
        <quiz>25</quiz>
    </quizzes>
    <projects>
        <project>48</project>
        <project>60</project>
        </projects>
    <exams>
        <exam>38</exam>
        <exam>48</exam>
        <exam>66</exam>
    </exams>
    </student>
    </S_db>
```

Output to be generated is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF‑8"?>
<projects>
<student>
<name>Barb Wire</name>
<total>108</total>
</student>
<student>
<name>Guy Wire</name>
<total>80</total>
</student>
<student>
<name>Rusty Nail</name>
<total>96</total>
</student>
```

I tried to generate Xquery as follows:

```
    <student>
   {for $i in (1 to 3) return
   <total> { for $a in /S_db
   let $s := sum($a/student[$i]/projects/project)
   let $name := $a/student[$i]/name
   return ($s)}
   </total>
   }
  </student>
```

My Current Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student>
<total>96</total>
<total>80</total>
<total>108</total>
</student>
```

I don't know how to get that name tag with corresponding total tag.
I have stored the name element of particular student in name variable

Comment: Could you post the current output here?

Comment: ERROR - Unexpected token "{" in path expression

Comment: Try this: `<student>
   {for $i in (1 to 3) return
   <Name> { for $a in /S_db
   let $name := $a/student[$i]/name
   return ($name)}
   </name>
   }
   {for $i in (1 to 3) return
   <total> { for $a in /S_db
   let $s := sum($a/student[$i]/projects/project)
   let $name := $a/student[$i]/name
   return ($s)}
   </total>
   }
  </student>` @rishi

Comment: It generates the output like: first all the name of student and after that total element but I want alternative output like: first name then corresponding total.please try to generate output like that.@Thirisangu

Comment: ERROR - expected "}", found "{" @Thirisangu

Comment: ERROR - Unexpected token "{" in path expression @Thirisangu

Comment: Sorry remove the first `{for $i in (1 to 3) return` and try

Comment: I tried this: <student> {for $i in (1 to 3) return <name> { for $a in /S_db let $name := $a/student[$i]/name return ($name)} </name> <total> { for $a in /S_db let $s := sum($a/student[$i]/projects/project) let $name := $a/student[$i]/name return ($s)} </total> } </student>
Output: ERROR - Unexpected token "{" in path expression

Comment: the query you tried was wrong one :(

Comment: After Removing first for loop:
Xquery: <student> {for $i in (1 to 3) return <name> { for $a in /S_db let $name := $a/student[$j]/name return ($name)} </name> <total> { for $a in /S_db let $s := sum($a/student[$i]/projects/project) let $name := $a/student[$i]/name return ($s)} </total> } </student>
Output: ERROR - Variable $j has not been declared

Comment: `<student> {for $j in (1 to 3)` add _$j_ OR replace _$j_ with _$i_

Comment: I replaced $j with $i:
Output: ERROR - Unexpected token "{" in path expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible way :**

```
<projects>
{
    for $s in /S_db/student
    return 
    <student>
    {
        $s/name,
        <total>{sum($s/projects/project)}</total>
    }
    </student>
}
</projects>
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/5d0e344d249297fb8918670b06e1ffaa)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
   <student>
      <name>Rusty Nail</name>
      <total>96</total>
   </student>
   <student>
      <name>Guy Wire</name>
      <total>80</total>
   </student>
   <student>
      <name>Barb Wire</name>
      <total>108</total>
   </student>
</projects>
```